# Android 5.0 ActivityManager's getRunningTasks() method is not working

Tags: android

I use the the below code to get the name of the application that is on the top.but on Android 5.0, it always give the same name of the application having package name(com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox). below code does not give the name of the application that is on the top.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
RunningTaskInfo taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);                

String packageName = taskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
```

On Android 5.0 how I can get the name of the application that is on the top?

Answer (score 0):

> Android 5.0 ActivityManager's getRunningTasks()

It has been deprecated from Android L. I don't think anyway to get it now.

Comment: but,applications like applocker still showing the lock screen for the locked applications when locked application application come to top.